# Tensorflow (tf-slim) Model with is_training True and False

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I would like to run a given model both on the train set (`is_training=True`) and on the validation set (`is_training=False`), specifically with how `dropout` is applied. Right now the [prebuilt models](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2a99dcba2c3a4429ad13206c1878a70d753d05e1/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/overfeat.py#L72) expose a parameter `is_training` that is passed it the `dropout` layer when building the network. The issue is that If I call the method twice with different values of `is_training`, I will get two different networks that do no share weights (I think?).  How do I go about getting the two networks to share the same weights such that I can run the network that I have trained on the validation set?

Comment: I think the default behavior is to share weights between the two cases, so you don't have anything to do. `tf-slim` uses `tf.get_variable()` which reuses variables between calls.

Comment: Okay, I think this mostly works. You need to make sure `scope` is set and then for safety seems best to also set `reuse=True`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a solution with your comment to use Overfeat in train and test mode. (I couldn't test it so you can check if it works?)

First some imports and parameters:

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim
overfeat = tf.contrib.slim.nets.overfeat

batch_size = 32
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 231, 231, 3])
dropout_keep_prob = 0.5
num_classes = 1000
```

---

In train mode, we pass a **normal scope** to the function `overfeat`:

```py
scope = 'overfeat'
is_training = True

output = overfeat.overfeat(inputs, num_classes, is_training,         
                           dropout_keep_prob, scope=scope)
```

---

Then in test mode, we create the same scope but with `reuse=True`.

```py
scope = tf.VariableScope(reuse=True, name='overfeat')
is_training = False

output = overfeat.overfeat(inputs, num_classes, is_training,         
                           dropout_keep_prob, scope=scope)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a placeholder for is_training:

```
isTraining = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

# create nn
net = ...
net = slim.dropout(net,
                   keep_prob=0.5,
                   is_training=isTraining)
net = ...

# training
sess.run([net], feed_dict={isTraining: True})

# testing
sess.run([net], feed_dict={isTraining: False})
```

Comment: I tried this and ran into problems because the variables were not being reused. I also encountered memory restrictions that I couldn't explain.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the case, the solutions are different.

My first option would be to use a different process to do the evaluation. You only need to check that there is a new checkpoint and load that weights into the evaluation network (with `is_training=False`):

```
checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self.checkpoints_path)
# wait until a new check point is available
while self.lastest_checkpoint == checkpoint:
    time.sleep(30)  # sleep 30 seconds waiting for a new checkpoint
    checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(self.checkpoints_path)
logging.info('Restoring model from {}'.format(checkpoint))
self.saver.restore(session, checkpoint)
self.lastest_checkpoint = checkpoint
```

The second option is after every epoch you unload the graph and create a new evaluation graph. This solution waste a lot of time loading and unloading graphs.

The third option is to share the weights. But feeding these networks with queues or dataset can lead to issues, so you have to be very careful. I only use this for Siamese networks.

```
with tf.variable_scope('the_scope') as scope:
    your_model(is_training=True)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    your_model(is_training=False)
```